# $\sqrt[n]{m}$ is irrational if $m$ is not the nth power of an integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm reading the book *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory* by Ireland and Rosen, and I think that there is an exercise which is false.

The exercise says:

Prove that " $\sqrt[n]{m}$ is irrational if $m$ is not the nth power of an integer".

Okey, a counterexemple for this proposition is that:

Taking $$ m = \frac{8}{27},  n = 3$$

$m$ is an irreductible fraction and $$\sqrt[3]{\frac{8}{27}} = \frac{2}{3} \in \mathbb{Q}$$

with the propierty that  $$\nexists k\in \mathbb{Z} / \frac{8}{27} = k^3$$
In this counterexample we can see that m is not the nth power of an integer but $\sqrt[3]{\frac{8}{27}}$ is rational.

Am I right?

PD: If we suppose that $ m \in \mathbb{Z}$ we can prove that.

First we are going to prove this Lemma:

**Lemma:** $ q^n | p^n \Rightarrow q|p$

*Proof (by contrapositive):*

We have to show that: $  q \not|p \Rightarrow q^n \not| p^n $

We will denote the set of primes as $\mathbb{P}$. Note that we assume that elements in $\mathbb{Z}$ have a unique factorization.

$q \not|p \Rightarrow \exists \alpha \in \mathbb{P} / \alpha | q  \wedge \alpha \not| p \Rightarrow \alpha | q^n \wedge \alpha \not| p^n \Rightarrow \forall t \in  \{ t \in \mathbb{Z} : (\exists s \in \mathbb{Z})(t = sq^n) \} \alpha|t \Rightarrow p^n \not\in \{ t \in \mathbb{Z} : (\exists s \in \mathbb{Z})(t = sq^n) \} \Rightarrow q^n \not| p^n \\ \Box$

Now we can prove the main proposition:

**Proposition:**  $\sqrt[n]{m}$ is irrational if $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ is not the nth power of an integer

*Proof:*

$$\sqrt[n]{m} = \frac{p}{q} \Leftrightarrow m = \frac{p^n}{q^n} \Rightarrow \frac{p^n}{q^n} \in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow q^n | p^n \Rightarrow q|p \Rightarrow  \exists t \in \mathbb{Z} / qt = p \Rightarrow \frac{p^n}{q^n} = (\frac{p}{q})^n = t^n = m $$

$\Box$

Comment: It is probably assumed that $m$ is an integer, but the author perhaps didn't make the assumption clear.

Comment: If it's number theory, you probably want $m$ to be a natural number.

Comment: Thank you. But if we are talking about integers it's trivial that if $m$ is not an nth power of a integer then $\sqrt[n]{m}$ is irrational by definition of powers and roots (I think, correct me if it is false).

Comment: @rbbau: It is not trivial. Although it is assumed that $m$ is an integer, it is not a priori assumed that $\sqrt[n]{m}$ can only be integer or irrational.  You have to rule out the possibility of $\sqrt[n]{m}$ being a non-integer rational number.  This includes as special cases that $\sqrt2$ is irrational, $\sqrt[3]{17}$ is irrational, etc.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer thank you, I'm going to study that case and I will tell you my results when I reach a conclusion.

Comment: @rbbau You need to justify your claim $\, q^n\mid p^n \,\Rightarrow\, q\mid p,\, $ which is the crux of the matter.

Comment: @BillDubuque I think that this proof of the lemma is correct, could you say me if I am right? Thank you

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122, rational numbers are rarely used in number theory, e.g., a rational number $\frac{a}{b}$ with $(a,b)=1$ is called a reduced fraction. 
Of course they would have mentioned it in the exercise, though.

Comment: @rbbau You need to assume $\,p,q\,$ coprime. If you are using uniqueness of prime factorization (or some equivalent) in your proof of the Lemma then you should explicitly state that.